# How to generate the certificate and key for HTTP/2 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

I have a node.js application. I'm using http and it works. But I want to use http2 for my application. I have installed the module from npm:

```
npm install http2
```

And I use it like this: ( app variable is defined, my application works with HTTP perfectly.)

```
var http2 =require('http2') ;
var server=http2.createServer(app);
```

But this does not work and  I get "could not get any response" error from POSTMAN.

When I write ***var http2= require('http')*** , this is working without any problem.

I looked at Http/2 documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example

And There is something written here that i dont understand:

```
To generate the certificate and key for this example, run:

 openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj '/CN=localhost' \
  -keyout localhost-privkey.pem -out localhost-cert.pem
```

Where will I write these codes and run? I could not find.

Comment: It's not code, it's a command. `openssl` is a program you need to install and run with the arguments listed there. A simple internet search on "openssl" will find that out, instructions on how to install it, etc.

Comment: also you need to alter your code to work with https, its in the docs you linked

Comment: Also, "

This package has been deprecated

Author message:
Use the built-in module in node 9.0.0 or newer, instead" you don't and should not need to install. it comes with node.js

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to run this command in a Terminal, so on Windows that could be powershell, Konsole or Terminal on Linux or MacOS. You might have to install openssl with your operating systems package manager. I would suggest googling:

"Install openssl $your_os_here"

and then it will generate some files you can use from within your node code